# Multiple rows for same user - but I do not need all of them

Tags: sql, oracle, rows

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
USER_ID START_DATE END_DATE     PRODUCT_ID
1       2015-07-20 2016-07-20   1
1       2003-10-25 2009-01-14   0
2       2007-10-04 2008-05-05   1
```

And so forth.

What I do want to create is a table like this:

```
USER_ID   PAYER   EXPAYER   BASIC
1         0       1         0
2         0       0         1
```

I do need it like this, since I want to join it afterwards and group by city.
However, I have multiple entries in the table per USER_D (as shown above).

I define a payer by saying it is someone who has an entry PRODUCT_ID=1, so that today's date is in-between START and END_DATE it.

An ex-payer is someone who had at least one such entry and has not anymore.

A basic customer is anyone else.

By doing this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE MEMBERSHIP AS
SELECT 
  USER_ID, 
  COUNT( CASE WHEN PRODUCT_ID=1 AND (CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN DG_START_DATE AND DG_END_DATE) THEN 1 END ) AS 'PAYER', 
  COUNT( CASE WHEN PRODUCT_ID=1 AND (CURRENT_DATE NOT BETWEEN DG_START_DATE AND DG_END_DATE) THEN 1 END ) AS 'EXPAYER', 
  COUNT( CASE WHEN NET_PRICE = 0  THEN 1 END ) AS 'BASIC' 
FROM CONTRACTS;
```

However, my result has for example entries like this, which is wrong:

```
USER_ID    PAYER     EXPAYER    BASIC
1          4         2          4
```

and so forth...

Thank you very much!

Comment: where is column `NET_PRICE` coming from? Your sample data and desired output doesn't match. what is the logic for column`BASIC`?

Comment: BTW: Are you sure you want to use the session-dependent `CURRENT_DATE` and not `SYSDATE` instead?

Comment: Simple Copy and paste mistake. Wanted to keep my problem as simple as possible, NET_PRICE is not important here but existing in the actual table.
And I did not know about the mistake in using CURRENT_DATE, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`:

```
COUNT( CASE WHEN PRODUCT_ID=1 ...
```

shoud become

```
SUM (CASE WHEN PRODUCT_ID=1 ... then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: `SUM` over ones and zeros is just another way of writing `COUNT` over non-nulls. Maybe you meant `MAX` instead?

Comment: You are right, count over non-nulls does the same thing. I prefer Sum because it's more clear for me. @ThorstenKettner

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement should result in a syntax error, because it is lacking `GROUP BY user_id`. Moreover you are using single quotes on alias names which should be double quotes (though they are completely superfluous here).

The three types exclude each other; a user is *either* payer *or* expayer *or* basic. So use one CASE construct for this. You can make this three different columns in a second step, though this doesn't make much sense as always one column will be 1 and the others 0. A better option would be a second table for the types and one column for the type in the membership table.

```
create or replace table membership as 
select 
  user_id,
  case when type = 'payer' then 1 else 0 end as payer,
  case when type = 'expayer' then 1 else 0 end as expayer,
  case when type = 'basic' then 1 else 0 end as basic
from
(
  select 
    user_id, 
    case when count(case when product_id = 1 and current_date between dg_start_date and dg_end_date then 1 end) > 0 then 'payer'
         when count(case when product_id = 1 then 1 end) > 0 then 'expayer'
         else 'basic'
    end as type
  from contracts
  group by user_id
);
```

Comment: Thanks mate, the statement works mostly. However, it does not work for the second "when" statement in the inner select. [when count(case when product_id = 1 ) > 0 then 'expayer']. It gives me a syntax error, "unexpected ')', expecting OR_ or THEN_)

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I only saw your comments now. I've corrected the flawed case expression in my answer.